# How to read from Rails cache atomically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have 2 processes running. The user action that basically does this:

```
      Rails.cache.fetch("items/#{self.id}/default_as_json") do
        super(root: false,
              :only => get_only_show,
              :methods => get_include_methods
        )
      end
```

On page load

Then I have another process, that does not run as often. Maybe once every 2 weeks, but it runs for a couple hours.
This process is doing a lot of data processing and after a lot of testing the best option I came up with was just to clear the entire cache after each step. So the website served the most up to date information. The performance cost of this is not much of an issue.
I am essentially running into a race condition on page load. It seems like it is finding the existence of the key, but by the time it goes to read the key the file has been deleted.
This is the stack trace I am seeing when this happens:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - [CACHE_LOCATION]/A95/DD0/.permissions_check.70057658850120.4451.366289):
    43:       <% if object_type == "Item" %>
    44:         <%= render(
    45:           partial: 'items/no_table_row',
    46:           locals: {object: this_object.as_json,
    47:                   singlesearch: true}
    48:         ) %>
    49:       <% elsif object_type == "Ability" %>
  app/models/item.rb:202:in `serializable_hash'
  app/views/poly_single_searches/_search_list.html.erb:46:in `block in _app_views_poly_single_searches__search_list_html_erb__1164541304050581354_70057643074520'
  app/views/poly_single_searches/_search_list.html.erb:35:in `_app_views_poly_single_searches__search_list_html_erb__1164541304050581354_70057643074520'
  app/views/poly_single_searches/fetch_search.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_poly_single_searches_fetch_search_html_erb___2217227932112086773_70057643107440'
  app/controllers/poly_single_searches_controller.rb:14:in `fetch_search'


  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (7.5ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (11.0ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (26.0ms)
```

When this other process is not running, everything works perfectly. I have it as a task to figure out a better way to clear caching, right now not clearing the cache after each step is not an option.
One solution I have is wrapping the Rails.cache.fetch in a rescue for this however that may just keep failing until it manages to run fast enough.

Comment: One way to handle this is to use Redis as cache backend and apply an approach [described here](http://redis.io/topics/distlock). Another is to use a Mutex and do something [like this](https://gist.github.com/torkale/2762063).

Comment: I was thinking about looking at a different caching solution. I was not sure if that would actually fix my problem since the Rails side of the code would be the same.

Comment: You can use Redis as Rails cache backend. See [redis-store](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) gem. Using it will not require much change to your code.

Comment: Is there a way I can disable caching without needing to modify every place I am doing caching? I am exploring all possible options, one thing I thought of was when this process was running just disable caching completely.

Comment: There is `config.cache_store = :null_store` but I'm not sure whether it supports switching on the fly.

Comment: I just tried doing  `Rails.application.configure do` with both the cache_store and the perform_caching. It did not complain but it did not actually take affect. That may not be an option, I am just trying to get all my options on the table so I can figure out what works best.

Comment: It is ugly and it would require me modifying everywhere I am doing cache so it may not be a good idea, but it may accomplish basically disabling cache. There is an argument for 'Rails.cache.fetch', 'force: true' which looks like it makes it ignore/rebuild the cache. I could set that as a site paramater

Comment: Or you could create a decorator for cache which would implement whatever change of behaviour you need. You would still have to update all the code that uses cache but this, hopefully, would be a more future-proof solution.

Comment: After testing, that by itself is not a solution. It is still trying to do something with the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question, however https://stackoverflow.com/users/2116518/nic-nilov deserves the credit.
In testing switching to using Redis instead of the built in Ruby solution fixed my problem. It looks like the way the request works is different and less fragile.
So far I have not needed to implement http://redis.io/topics/distlock , since just switching to Redis so far has fixed my issue in testing.